# In Angular where should I store a user object so that I can reference it for availability in navigation settings?

Tags: angular, authentication

Fairly new to Angular coming from ASP.NET. I have an app that I'm rewriting that has a fairly complex security structure and I need navigation components to reflect  not only the simple role of the user but additional privileges within that role. Looking for help on where to "store" this user object so that I'm maintaining least trips to the back end service to get these details all while maintaining security within my code.

As with what looks to be all Angular apps I have a AuthService created which I would like to have perform all of these functions and then hold the settings for the currently logged on User.

Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Answer (score -1):

As per [**Angular StyleGuide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-11):

> Do put a singleton service whose instance will be shared throughout the application in the CoreModule (e.g. ExceptionService and LoggerService).

So you can create an `AuthService` in your `CoreModule` and then import this `CoreModule` in your `AppModule`. In this `AuthService` you can implement a `private` `BehaviorSubject` and expose it `asObservable`, something along the lines of this:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { User } from '@app/shared/models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
  user$ = this.user.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(credentials: User) {
    return this.http.post(...)
      .subscribe(user => this.user.next(user));
  }

  ...

}
```

You can simply `subscribe` to `user$` in your `ngOnInit` life-cycle hook method by injecting `AuthService` as a dependency in your Component(s) to get access to the currently logged-in user.

Since this is going to be a Singleton and its instance will be shared throughout the application, you will have access to it anywhere in your App.

You might also want to use [**`ngx-permissions`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions) which helps you implement permission and roles based access control for your Angular App.